# How can we change the icon and title of expo go push notification?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, push-notification, expo

I'm trying to change the icon and title of the push notification. I don't know why my changes are not taking place.

My `app.json` is like :

```
"name": "textApp",
"slug": "textApp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",

"notification": {
  "icon": "./assets/logo.png",
  "color": "#311b92",
  "androidMode": "default",
  "androidCollapsedTitle": "Updates from Colab.notes",
  "iosDisplayInForeground": true
},

"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-notifications",
    {
      "icon": "./assets/logo.png",
      "color": "#ffffff"
    }
  ]
],
```

1. I'm updating my app by pressing **r** .
2. I have also removed the cache by `expo r c`
3. The logo.png image size is square. 500x500px exactly.

icon root structure.

[image]

I'm trying to customize indicating properties...

[image]

Comment: As I cant comment I'll write it here, did you ever managed to get the icon to change? Im having the same problem, already did and re-did everything on the docs and so one with icon, white, grayscale, 96x96 and nothing really works for me.

Comment: Yeah same in my case..

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this? I have same issue in iOS with stand alone app  from Test Flight and Still get the Expo Go title and the expo icon.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to specify `message.title` to make it work:

```js
await expo.sendPushNotificationsAsync([
  {
    to: pushToken,
    sound: 'default',
    title: 'Some title', // Add this
    subtitle: 'Some subtitle',
    body: 'Hello world!',
  },
])
```

Preview: [expo notification with custom title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezqcu.jpg)